# Most efficient way to render data into a form from a populated model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've got a populated entity filled with checkbox selector, few strings. that has to be built linearly(for each row) in a loop in a div structure.

The entity:

```
public class Hours
{
   [Key] 
   public int SliceID { get; set; }
   public string SliceName { get; set; }
   public string Slice { get; set; } 
   public string StartTime { get; set; }
   public string EndTime { get; set; }
   public bool Selected { get; set; } //if slice is checked by user on search screen
}
```

The action which will gather all time slices for display:

```
public ActionResult Search_Times()
{
    int iInstId = 1;

    Test.Models.DataLayer db = new Test.Models.DataLayer();
    Test.Models.TestDB context = new Models.TestDB();

    IEnumerable<Test.Models.Hours> lst = db.GetSlices(context, iInstId).OrderBy(a => a.SliceID);
 //   ViewBag.SliceList = lst;
    return View(lst);

}
```

I want to render those fields in a specific part of my body page along with some class/div formatting along the way.

For example, If I use EditorForModel :

in Main page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Hours>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

in the Hours EditorTemplate:

```
@model Test.Models.Hours
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
        x => x.Selected, 
        new { 
            @class = "jcf-unselectable",
            id = HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("cb_slice." + ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
        }
    )
// this should be a label too, made for example to show text from data.
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.SliceName)



    @Html.LabelFor(
    x=> x.StartTime,
        new { 
            @class = "info"

        })

    @Html.LabelFor(
    x => x.EndTime, 
        new { 
            @class = "info"

        })

</div>
```

The @Html.LabelFor in my case will only show the row's title and not the data (for="" in the source view after rendering), Unlike DisplayTextFor which will show the data but is only a generic text.

I need a way or to fix this current way, To manipulate the data from the model accordingly, Labels will show the data behind their field and I could generate the class,id needed(based on css/html required) inside that label in a loop.

What's the best way to do so, viewbags/templates/etc?

Comment: Your code hurt my eyes, specially your Hours model and the [Key] attribute that you most likely set as a parameter in on of you controller's action.

Comment: Apologies, The code is teared up to show the specific case.
Please don't just criticize, If you got some improvement be my guest.

Comment: So you're not using the class Hours as a parameter in one of your actions are you?

Comment: Made an edit with the action that uses the Hours class to get the data for display.